# How to get Image ID of docker in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile, docker-compose

I need to run docker container through Jenkins.
For that I used "**Start/Stop Docker Containers**" as build step

Start/Stop Docker Containers

```
Action to choose        : Run container
Docker Cloud name       : docker_demo
ID                      : DOCKER_IMAGE_ID
DNS     
Port bindings           :port
Bind all declared ports :   
Hostname                : ip address
```

While running the job,it is telling that "Invalid ID".
Can anyone suggest,How to get Image ID of docker in jenkins??

Comment: Isn't it just the image name like `ubuntu:latest`?

Comment: Nope.Actually i created one image(which is created while execution time of jenknis job) using docker.repositry(local).Now I need to retrieve that image ID.So how to retrieve it??

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? It seems from the question you may be confused about the difference between a container and an image.

Answer (score 21):

One liner based on [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output):

```
sudo docker images --filter=reference=image_name --format "{{.ID}}"
```

Replace `image_name` by your actual docker image name.
You can store that value in a shell variable for further referencing with:

`IMAGE_ID=$(sudo docker images --filter=reference=image_name --format "{{.ID}}")`

And then access it with `$IMAGE_ID`

Comment: don't forget to close parenthesis at the end:  `IMAGE_ID=$(docker images --filter=reference=image_name --format "{{.ID}}")`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Tabaraei, I fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

A simpler way to solve it:

```
docker images --filter="reference=your_image_name" --quiet
```

What this command means:

- --filter : Search a image based on name (represented by *your_image_name*)
- --quiet : Return only the image ID

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: --no-trunc is also needed here

Answer (score 3):

You can see the docker image id (for the images you have built or pulled from docker hub) using the following command: `docker images`

Update after comments from OP:

`docker images --filter` only implements dangling=true so you can't search for container ids using this way. so you'll have to rely on shell scripting, here's an example:

```
docker images | grep -E '^golang.*latest' | awk -e '{print $3}'
```

You'll need to tailor the regex in the grep to match your image name and tag.

Comment: yup.that way i did.but it is static.(every time i need to change the id,if content of image is modified).I need a dynamic id(some sort of variable) so that it will automatically fetch the updated image id from the repository.

Comment: docker images --filter now supports searching by reference
$ docker images --filter=reference='busy*:*libc' and also format to choose format of the output see [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering)

Answer (score 0):

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}" | head -1
```

Placeholder

.ID

.Repository

.Tag

.Digest

.CreatedSince

.CreatedAt

.Size