# An image does not exist locally with the tag: while pushing image to local registry

Tags: docker, push, local, docker-registry, minikube

I am trying to push an image to a local registry running in minikube but get the below error:

```
Successfully built ee84225eb459
Successfully tagged user/apiserver:0.0.1

$ docker push localhost:5000/user/apiserver:0.0.1

The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/user/apiserver]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: localhost:5000/user/apiserver
```

I have already tried starting minikube with below:

```
minikube start --vm-driver xhyve --insecure-registry localhost:5000
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Comment: For me, the answer was simple but annoying to find I forgot to tag my image with the **username** also i made it private do not know if thats really neccesary please let me know if thats the case. so other people can learn from it and me :) thnx for this post it was helpful.
btw sorry I am a little bit off-topic.

Comment: `docker push` should really return a a clearer error message, like `push of image with tag X failed because no image with tag X was found`.

Answer (score 51):

You need to **tag** and **push** the image. When tagging an image, you can use the image identifier (imageId). It is listed when showing the list of all images with **docker images**.
Syntax and an example (using imageId) for creating a tag are:

```
docker tag <imageId or imageName> <hostname>:<repository-port>/<image>:<tag>
docker tag af340544ed62 example.com:18444/hello-world:mytag
```

Once the tag, which can be equivalent to a version, is created successfully, you can confirm its creation with **docker images** and issue the **push** with the syntax:

```
docker push <hostname>:<repository-port>/<image>:<tag>
```

[There is an example for local nexus repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/pushing-images)

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining how to add a tag. The top post does not detail this. Recommend this being the top post.

Comment: This is the best awnser about how to push image, because without tag you can't and thats the only post that explain how to add tag. Thanks!

Comment: This answer should be accepted

Answer (score 42):

I was getting the same error, which OP is referring to, googling the exact phrase brought me here, but, in my case, I was pushing it to the default/public repository (hub.docker.com) instead of the local one. But as it turns out the issue was the same

This was my local image which I created on my disk

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
centos                 latest    927311af2297   20 hours ago   193MB
```

I tagged it like this:

```
docker tag centos devopskalsym:latest
```

then confirmed the tag being created:

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
devopskalsym           latest    927311af2297   20 hours ago   193MB
centos                 latest    927311af2297   20 hours ago   193MB
```

Since my repository on docker hub was: **devopskalsym/centos7**, I tried to push it:

```
docker push devopskalsym/centos7:latest
```

and got the error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker push devopskalsym/centos7:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/devopskalsym/centos7]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: devopskalsym/centos7
```

so I removed the tag with:

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker rmi devopskalsym
Untagged: devopskalsym:latest
```

then re-tagged correctly with the format mentioned by @BMitch.

```
docker tag centos:latest devopskalsym/centos7:latest
```

the format used is this: `docker tag local-image:tagname new-repo:tagname`

now it correctly shows the images:

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
devopskalsym/centos7   latest    927311af2297   20 hours ago   193MB
centos                 latest    927311af2297   20 hours ago   193MB
```

then pushed it again:

```
docker push devopskalsym/centos7:latest
```

and it worked

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-195 centos]# docker push devopskalsym/centos7:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/devopskalsym/centos7]
b7d51bf3d09e: Pushing [==================================>                ]    132MB/193.3MB
```

Note: you might need to login with `docker login`

Comment: in summary its 2 commands  ```1. docker tag <source image_name> <target image_name>  2. docker push reponame:<target image_name>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair off :D

Answer (score 24):

```
Successfully tagged user/apiserver:0.0.1

docker push localhost:5000/user/apiserver:0.0.1
```

Image tags need to include the registry name/port for you to push them anywhere other than the default registry (docker hub). So you need to tag your image as `localhost:5000/user/apiserver:0.0.1` rather than `user/apiserver:0.0.1`. Then you'll be able to push to your local registry.

Comment: Successfully built 8c921763a005
Successfully tagged localhost:5000/user/apiserver:0.0.1
docker push localhost:5000/user/apiserver:0.0.1
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/user/apiserver]
Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: Also this is after kubectl port-forward $POD 5000:5000 & where POD is my registry-7f8lq or registry pod which did not help either

Comment: bash-3.2$ curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
Handling connection for 5000
{"repositories":[]}

Comment: You'll want to open a separate question for that. This is moving from why can't it find my image to why isn't my port forward working.

Comment: Thanks - was able to get it to work with another local registry deployment and port forwarding - Reference link https://mtpereira.com/local-development-k8s.html

Answer (score 13):

I had an image

```
trip-bot                     latest     0c9e8f0367bc   36 minutes ago   955MB
```

And I was getting error

> The push refers to repository [docker.io/ilkhr/trip-bot]
> An image does not exist locally with the tag: ilkhr/trip-bot

**Solved the problem like this**

```
$ docker tag 0c9e8f0367bc ilkhr/trip-bot:trip-bot
```

After that I did so

```
$ docker push ilkhr/trip-bot:trip-bot
```

Comment: The problem is regarding the host of the registry missing, the question asker already tagged with the username. Represented by `user`. This answer sadly does not add anything of value. Sorry.

Comment: How do you tag in github actions when automating your builds? How do you get the image id?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63486511/14274230

Comment: @ИльяХоришко Thanks. I figured it out. When you build an image using ```build -t some_name``` you can reference it with the name ```some_name```. And even multi-tagging. Allows me to always tag versioned releases with the 'latest' tag.

Answer (score 12):

1. **first start with docker login with these commands:-**

   ```
   docker login
   ```
2. **then check you image id / tag by this command**

   ```
   docker images
   ```
3. **once you get your image id/tag then use this command to push to your dockerhub repository**

   ```
   docker tag <imageId or tag> <dockerhub id>/<imagename>:<tag>
   ```

or for general you can use

```
docker tag <imageId or tag> <hostname>:<repository-port>/<imagename>:<tag>
```

*note replace angle brackets with your specific information*

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, issues are *typically due to incorrect tagging*.

Here is a [working example deploying a docker to DockerHub](https://github.com/maciejskorski/software_engineering/actions/runs/4534128052/jobs/7987895193).

The tag format is `<namespace>/<repo_name>:<version>`. The namespace is typically stored in the repository secrets. Note that it is convenient to *assign a tag when building*.

```yaml
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths: ["Dockerfile",".github/workflows/docker-image.yaml"]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Docker Hub tag
    env:
      IMAGE_NAME: jupyter-book-gh
      IMAGE_VERSION: latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Log in to DockerHub
      env:
        DOCKER_USER: ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}
      run: |
        docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        echo "${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION"
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
    - name: Push the Docker image
      run: docker push ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to push to docker hub and get this tag error, have in mind that at the moment you build your image, you should state the username of your docker hub account in order to push it right.

So in my case, the **correct** command was

```
docker image build -t marcofloriano/hello-docker .
```

**And not**

docker image build -t hello-docker .

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when pushing to **AWS ECR**,

for me i had a typo,
the format current now as of 2023 is

```
docker tag image-id <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-code>.amazonaws.com/<repo-name>:<tag>
```

I accidentally deleted the dkr word, and I was getting the same error.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700278/6431037), if you receive this error while pushing to AWS ECR inside of a script, ensure the file line endings are appropriate for your OS (LF for Linux/OSX vs CRLF for Windows). This can be changed in most IDEs. For example, in VSCode by clicking the following tray tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem but I created the tag like proposed. Still, I got that very same error message.

The solution for me was to wait a little before pushing, apparently the local registry needs some 'settling time' to update itself(?)

A `sleep 10` between those two commands helped:

```
docker build . -t <my_tag>
sleep 10
docker push <my_tag>
```